# How to match parent height with vertical text view android?

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have such text view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/main_gray_text"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:background="#b0b4bc"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/plot_container"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_layout"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/plot_container">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:includeFontPadding="false"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="-5dp"
                            android:rotation="270"
                            android:text="@{map.get(12695)}"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:background="@color/red_color"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gray_text_guideline"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gray_text_guideline" />

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                            android:id="@+id/gray_text_guideline"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I have such UI in the end:

[image]

but I need to fill all height with such requirements:

- one line for this text
- fill all height (width of vertical text view)

I tried to fix it via LinearLayout but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

make textView height matchparent(Copt and paste this)

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/main_gray_text"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:background="#b0b4bc"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/plot_container"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_layout"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/plot_container">
    
                            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="-5dp"
                                android:rotation="270"
                                android:text="@{map.get(12695)}"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:background="@color/red_color"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gray_text_guideline"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gray_text_guideline" />
    
                            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                                android:id="@+id/gray_text_guideline"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
    
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: no, it did not help, I don't see any text at all

Comment: make rotation 0.

Comment: yes, but it breaks vertical text view in such case